# how to get the count of vehicles started from each place

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a table where there is entry of each vehicle at different time.

```
vehicle_ id         time                 place
____________        _____               ________
     1        2016-09-01 10:00:00          10
     2        2016-09-01 10:00:00          12
     1        2016-09-01 10:01:00          10
     1        2016-09-01 10:01:10          10
     3        2016-09-01 10:02:00          15
     2        2016-09-01 10:03:00          18
     1        2016-09-01 10:03:00          12
     2        2016-09-01 10:04:00          10
     2        2016-09-01 10:05:00          10
     1        2016-09-01 10:06:00          15
     2        2016-09-01 10:07:00          18
     3        2016-09-01 10:09:00          19
     4        2016-09-01 11:06:00          15
     1        2016-09-01 11:07:00          18
     3        2016-09-01 11:09:00          19
     4        2016-09-01 11:10:00          15
     2        2016-09-01 11:11:00          18
     6        2016-09-01 11:12:00          19
     4        2016-09-01 11:16:00          15
     5        2016-09-01 11:17:00          18
     3        2016-09-01 11:19:00          19
```

I want to know how many vehicles have been started sending data from a time period from which place?For example from 10:00 to 11:00 3 vehicles have started sending signals and vehicle 1 started from place 10 and vehicle 2 from place 12 and vehicle 3 from place 15. And from 11:00 to 12:00 vehicle 4 started from place 15 and vehicle 5 started from place 18 and vehicle 6 started from place 19.

So the final output will be

```
For 10-11

place         vehicle_count
_____         _____________
 10                1
 12                1
 15                1   
 For 11-12

place         vehicle_count
_____         _____________
 15                1(vehicle_id 4)
 18                1(vehicle_id 5)
 19                1(vehicle_id 6) 
For 10-12

place         vehicle_count
_____         _____________
 10                1(vehicle_id 1)
 12                1(vehicle_id 2)
 15                2(vehicle_id 3,4)
 18                1(vehicle_id 5)
 19                1(vehicle_id 6)
```

I did

```
select count(distinct(vehicle_id)) from public.datatable where time>=2016-09-01 10:00:00  and time<2016-09-01 11:00:00
```

But this gives the count from all places but how to get the origin places only.(which means vehicle id 1 is originated from place 10 so it should be counted under place 10 only).Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with Java?

Comment: @RealSkeptic No I asked that if SQL is not powerful enough then can try with JAVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

You can get the first location for each vehicle during the time period using `distinct on`, and then aggregate to get the `place`:

```
select place, count(*)
from (select distinct on (vehicle_id) dt.*
      from public.datatable dt
      where time >= '2016-09-01 10:00:00' and time < '2016-09-01 11:00:00'
      order by vehicle_id, time
     ) v
group by place;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a GROUP BY:

```
select place, count(*) 
from public.datatable
where 
time>=2016-09-01 10:00:00 and
time<2016-09-01 11:00:00
GROUP BY place
```

Comment: I don't think the solution would be a group by,Because I need one vehicle to come into one group only.But your query groups all the vehicle entries in the places

Answer (score 0):

```
select place, 
   count( distinct vehicle_id) from t t1
where
   tim>=to_date('2016-09-01 10:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS') and
   tim<to_date('2016-09-01 12:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS')
   and not exists (select * from t t2 where t1.tim >t2.tim and t1.vehicle_id=t2.vehicle_id) 
group by t1.place
order by t1.place;
```